# OnPush Change Detection for special cases

Tags: angular, typescript, web-component, angular2-changedetection

I develop an Angular 2 app with ngrx and I was interested by OnPush change detection to get better performance. I read several articles about it which said : "*If a component depends only on its input properties, and they are immutable, then this component can change if and only if one of its input properties changes.*". Therefore, I have two (simple) questions about OnPush :

1) If my component has a mix of @Input() properties and not input properties, Is OnPush useless ?

2) Same question for a component which has only properties (no @Input).

Thanks by advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OnPush does not affect components internal state.

If you look at this [excellent post](https://vsavkin.com/change-detection-in-angular-2-4f216b855d4c#.ya6iluh0k) by Victor Savkin, he specifically mentions

> It is worth noting that a component can still have private mutable
> state as long as it changes only due to inputs being updated or an
> event being fired from within the component’s template. The only thing
> the OnPush strategy disallows is depending on shared mutable state.
> Read more about it here.

It worth spending time on this post as well as the companion post he refers to.

Comment: You can also just call `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` or `ChangeDetectorRef.markForCheck()` to get change detection invoked after your code modified the state.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I don't understand something. If my component has no Input properties, OnPush is useless on it no ?

Comment: I don't think there is a real scenario where `OnPush` is useless. Perhaps if you don't have any bindings in your component. If you have some state that changes occasionally and bindings that are bound to this state, then `OnPush` allows you to limit change detection rate to the necessary minimum.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Ok ty dude. My last question and I will fully undertstand I guess. Assuming we have a components tree  (A-B-C-D-E-F-G). F fires an event. A is on OnPush detection strategy. Because of angular change detection start from the RootComponent (A) and it has one property (and no change appears on it), how change detection can go to the F component ? The Subtree of A must not be checked right ?

Comment: I think `F` can be considered to be within the template of `A`. If it's a DOM event that bubbles, then it definitely is an event in `A`s template, and change detection will run on the whole tree (if `G` is not `OnPush`). If it's an event of an `@Output()`, that is bound in `E`, then `E` will be marked for change detection. I'm not 100% sure but I assume this will also cause change detection to run for `A` and the whole tree to run.